# How to interact with a C++ program input stream from a Node.js process?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, io, cin

I'm new to Node.js but I'm not new to C++ and Javascript. I'm gonna make a C++ tool using node but I face a problem, when C++ program call `std::cin`, I don't know how to send data from node process to C++ process.

See this code (main.exe):

```
int main() {
  int a, b, c;
  cout << "Enter 3 numbers: ";
  cin >> a >> b >> c;
  cout << "Total: " << (a + b + c) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

In my javascript code, I use `child_process.spawn` to invoke main.exe, I know that I can use event `'data'` to get the message `"Enter 3 numbers: "`, but how do I let node enters `a`, `b` and `c` automatically and finally finish main.exe?

**UPDATE:**

My Javascript code (I don't know which event can be use to write data so I use `'data'`)

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('main.exe');
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  child.stdout.end('12 34 56');
});
child.on('close', (code) => console.log('Exit code: ' + code));
```

Comment: What have you tried? Nodejs should be able to write / pipe to the process you spawn.

Comment: @AndyM `pipe` is a method of a `writable` which I don't know how to apply to this, I just tried with `child.stdout.write` and `child.stdout.end` but none of them work.

Comment: Can you post some the javascript you are trying, too? Piping input would be like saying `echo "1 2 3" | ./main.exe` on the command line.

Comment: @AndyM I posted it, but that will not be used in my actual project, this code is for quick test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things,

- Your child process doesn't flush after `cout << "Enter 3 numbers: ";` so the `data` event is never getting triggered. (**Edit:** Reading your question again, it seems the data event is getting triggered. The buffering mechanism under Windows might be different than what I'm used to on Linux. I'll leave this here just in case though :)
- You need to write to `stdin` and not `stdout` for the child process.

Try this for your javascript code instead:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('main.exe');

child.stdin.end('12 34 56');
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
child.on('close', (code) => console.log('Exit code: ' + code));
```